# Getting list of duplicated rows from two different tables with key constriants

Tags: sql

I have three tables (Haven't specified table1 details since its not required)

```
# Table 2

step num | indeces | sample_num
         |         |
  step1  |   1     | sample1
  step2  |   2     | sample2
  step3  |   3     | sample3
  step4  |   2     | sample2
  step5  |   3     | sample3
```

step num is the Primary key and sample_num is the foreign key(pk in table 1)

```
# Table 3

   Name        | section |     timestamp      |   step num
               |         |                    |
  Mercedes     |   a     | 16.01.2020   00:11 |    step1
  Maruti       |   b     | 16.01.2020   00:12 |    step2
  Mini Cooper  |   c     | 16.01.2020   00:16 |    step3
  Porsche      |   d     | 16.01.2020   00:19 |    step4
  Vento        |   e     | 16.01.2020   00:21 |    step5
```

Here,  step num is the foreign key

I need the list of duplicate rows from the indeces column of table 2 and its corresponding timestamp rows from table 3.

```
# Expected Output

 indeces | timestamp 
         |         
  2      |16.01.2020   00:11
  2      |16.01.2020   00:12  
  3      |16.01.2020   00:19 
  3      |16.01.2020   00:21
```

My approach was to use JOIN and GROUPBY to get duplicated rows

```
SELECT indeces,timestamp
FROM table1,table2
JOIN (SELECT indeces
FROM table1 
GROUP BY indeces)
```

but somehow I have syntax issues in combining both the tables. Would be a great help if someone suggests me the correct query.

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: I don't understand the expected timestamps.  Your expected result does not seem to add up with the sample data.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen This is all sample data. I have just randomly mentioned values. I cannot give real-time data because of the security issues. I just want the list of duplicate indeces from table 2 and its corresponding timestamp values from table 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use window functions to find the duplicates and then `JOIN`:

```
select t2.indeces, t3.timestamp
from (select t2.*, count(*) over (partition by indeces) as cnt
      from table2 t2
     ) t2 join
     table3 t3
     on t2.stepnum = t3.stepnum
where cnt >= 2;
```

You haven't explained anything about `table1` but you can include that as you see fit.